# takes in a dictionary key and return an array filled with the appropriate values of the keys

Tags: ruby

Given the hash

```
person = { 
  "cats"=> 2,
  "dogs"=> 1
}
```

I wish to construct the array

```
["cats", "cats", "dogs"]
```

`"cats"` appears twice because `person["cats"] #=> 2`. For the same reason `"dogs"` appears once.  If the hash had a third key-value pair `"pigs"=>3`, I would want to return the array

```
["cats", "cats", "dogs", "pigs", "pigs", "pigs"]
```

I tried the following code.

```
arr = person.to_a    
i = 0
new_arr = []
while i < arr.length
  el = arr[i][0] 
  final = [new_arr << el]
  print final.flatten
  i += 1
end
```

This displays

```
["cats"]["cats", "dogs"] => nil
```

but does not seem to return a value.

```
new_arr
  #=> ["cats", "dogs"]
```

As you see, I am not getting the answer I wanted and do not understand why `print` displays what I show above.

I would like to know what is wrong with my code and what would be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I trust you find my my edit satisfactory. The main problem was that you did not clearly state the question. Instead, you assumed the reader could figure it out from the single example. As is often the case, however, multiple interpretation are possible. If the hash had three keys, for example, it's conceivable that you wanted the first key to appear three times, the second twice and the third just once, with the values being irrelevant. After you give the example *always* show the desired return value. Only then present your code, showing the return value and anything displayed...

Comment: ...Lastly, make sure that somewhere you clearly state what you want. I put that at the end because I assumed you wanted to know what was wrong with your code (so it should follow your code), as well as better ways of achieving the desired result, but in other situations it could be elsewhere. Incidentally, I asked my dog if she were a person. She went back to sleep.

Comment: It did help, thank you Cary! I will make sure to adopt the structure for future questions.

Comment: The reason you see `["cats"]["cats", "dogs"] => nil` is because you are using [Kernel#print](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print), which, unlike [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) (see also [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts)), does not add a newline when displaying a string...

Comment: ...If you could slow down the execution of your code you would see that it first displays `["cats"]`, then on the same line it adds `["cats", "dogs"]`, so you would see `["cats"]["cats", "dogs"]`. Lastly, when the `while` loop terminates it returns the value `nil`, shown as `=> nil` (followed by a newline). Normally you would see that on a separate line but since `print` was used, it is displayed at the end of the partially-completed line, so the line `["cats"]["cats", "dogs"] => nil` is displayed

Answer (score 2):

`flat_map` method will flatten multiple arrays into one

Array operator `*` creates array with multiple values

```
result = person.flat_map {|key, value| [key] * value}

# => ["cats", "cats", "dogs"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a lot of nice methods to work with collections. I believe it is better to use them instead of `while` loop.
You can iterate through the hash using [inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject)
 method. The first parameter in the block is the resulting array, that accumulates the result of each iteration, the second is a key/value pair.

```
person.inject([]) do |array, (key, value)|
  array + Array.new(value, key)
end
```

Or it can be rewritten as a one line.

```
person.inject([]) { |array, (key, value)| array + Array.new(value, key) }
```

Comment: I suggest one or another as everybody knows the alternate forms. Aside: "Here's a one-liner:" (sic), followed by a single line of code always brings a smile to my face, as it suggests that the reader might think that the line of code might in fact be multiple lines if not told otherwise. :-)

Comment: At least it makes you smile :) I wanted to clarify to the questioner tath it is the same example but in one line of code, because of @Zoh seems to be a newbie in Ruby.